# ¿Como hago para que INSERT INTO no me duplique registros?

Tags: php, mysql, android

Resulta que siempre cuando le doy al boton en la aplicacion de registrar, este o no vacio siempre lo inserta, que condicion necesito para que eso no pase, porque de verdad no es recomendable trabajar de esa manera.. solo quiero que si los campos van llenos inserte en caso contrario no inserte.. mas nada.

Mi codigo es:

```
<?php   

  $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "contrumeca");


  $proveedor = $_POST["proveedor"];
  $contacto = $_POST["contacto"];
  $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
  $direccion = $_POST["direccion"];        

  $statement = mysqli_prepare($conexion, "INSERT INTO proveedor (proveedor, contacto, telefono, direccion) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");    

  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssss", $proveedor, $contacto, $telefono, $direccion);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

  //Declarar el response *//


    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true; 





  echo json_encode($response);
```

Gracias.

Comment: El título habla sobre evitar duplicados, pero la pregunta habla sobre evitar que se tomen valores nulos, convendría que aclares lo que ocupas.

Comment: Porque inserta tanto vacios como llenos, si va vacio inserta, y si va lleno ok lo inserta, pero asi no me sirve, investigue tambien que con if isset funciona, intento hacerlo a ver.

Comment: 1. La tabla debe tener una restricción, a nivel de base de datos, que evite registros duplicados; 2. Antes de insertar debes verificar primero si el registro existe; 3. Entonces podrás mandar la inserción. Estás en el punto `3` sin haber cumplido los puntos 1 y 2. Eso se llama error de diseño, tu aplicación funcionará mal, muy mal, si te saltas etapas esenciales del control de los datos. Aquí no se vale argumentar que es demasiado pesado hacer los pasos 1 y 2. Hay que hacerlos, sí o sí, si quieres un modelo de datos robusto.